# Как проверить прогрузку SVG элемента на странице с Selenium+JUnit?

Tags: svg, selenium, тестирование, junit

На данный момент делаю screenshot-based тест SVG элементов. На одной странице их много, поэтому они прогружаются не одновременно. Была написана функция Wait, которая ждет появления определенного SVG на странице:

```
public void Wait(WebDriver driver, String XPath)
{
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(240, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 240);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(XPath)));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(XPath)));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath(XPath))));
}
```

Но она не работает правильно, т.к. периодически создаются скриншоты пустого места на странице. Программист сказал, что дело в том, что svg грузится параллельно с страницей. Я проверяю presenceofelement, он отвечает мне что embed уже появился, но на самом деле в embed-е еще нет файла svg. Как в таком случае подождать, пока SVG отобразится на странице?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium не может найти элементы представленные внутри embed-а. Для того чтобы это стало возможным нужно переключится на embed командой

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath(embedXPath)));
```

И можно работать с embed-ом как со страницей (т.е. функция Wait описанная выше становится рабочей). После завершения работы необходимо переключится обратно:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```